# Are new Charts Service features added recently?

Tags: google-apps-script

I mentioned that the GAS Chart Service contains a few methods which are not described in the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_charts). Does anyone know which purpose do they have? Where is possible to find documentation for them? The methods are

- `Charts.newDashboardPanel()`
- `Charts.newDataViewDefinition()`
- `Charts.newCategoryFilter()`
- `Charts.newNumberRangeFilter()`
- `Charts.newStringFilter()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These new features are in the final stages of being released, and we hope to have documentation and an announcement coming soon.